# XML Node is null in c#

Tags: c#, xml, yql

Alright so I'm trying to get information from Yahoo finance using their YQL. The below code is what I'm using for that. I have tested the xml location string in a browser which does return xml code. I'm trying to read that code, parse it and MessageBox the node I'm looking for. The error is that the string text is null, I'm presuming this is because node is null, which is probably because doc is null. Why is doc null?

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.stocks%20where%20symbol%3D%22" + txt_Symbol.Text + "%22&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys");
XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/results/stock/FullTimeEmployees");
string text = node.InnerText;
```

Sample Response From Yahoo YQL:

```
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="1" yahoo:created="2014-06-03T21:06:06Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
<diagnostics>
<url execution-start-time="0" execution-stop-time="1" execution-time="1">
<![CDATA[
http://www.datatables.org/yahoo/finance/yahoo.finance.stocks.xml
]]>
</url>
<publiclyCallable>true</publiclyCallable>
<cache execution-start-time="4" execution-stop-time="4" execution-time="0" method="GET" type="MEMCACHED">
<![CDATA[ bcd022d1d39e092a7a1390d6f5cf574a ]]>
</cache>
<cache execution-start-time="4" execution-stop-time="5" execution-time="1" method="GET" type="MEMCACHED">
<![CDATA[ 32c5f8788e8bc68ba5e635ae25257e23 ]]>
</cache>
<cache execution-start-time="5" execution-stop-time="6" execution-time="1" method="GET" type="MEMCACHED">
<![CDATA[ 8c548d6a60dd1f067626b9ecdf556eb3 ]]>
</cache>
<url execution-start-time="5" execution-stop-time="288" execution-time="283">
<![CDATA[ http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=ibm ]]>
</url>
<url execution-start-time="5" execution-stop-time="288" execution-time="283">
<![CDATA[ http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=ibm ]]>
</url>
<query execution-start-time="5" execution-stop-time="294" execution-time="289" params="{url=[http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=ibm]}">
<![CDATA[
select * from html where url=@url and xpath='//div[@id="yfi_investing_head"]/h1 | //div[@class="yfi_quote_summary"]/div[1]'
]]>
</query>
<url execution-start-time="5" execution-stop-time="430" execution-time="425">
<![CDATA[ http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=ibm ]]>
</url>
<url execution-start-time="5" execution-stop-time="430" execution-time="425">
<![CDATA[ http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=ibm ]]>
</url>
<url execution-start-time="7" execution-stop-time="455" execution-time="448">
<![CDATA[ http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=ibm ]]>
</url>
<query execution-start-time="4" execution-stop-time="434" execution-time="430" params="{url=[http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=ibm]}">
<![CDATA[
select * from html where url=@url and xpath='//table[@class="yfnc_datamodoutline1"]/tr/td/table/tr' limit 4
]]>
</query>
<url execution-start-time="7" execution-stop-time="455" execution-time="448">
<![CDATA[ http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=ibm ]]>
</url>
<query execution-start-time="6" execution-stop-time="461" execution-time="455" params="{url=[http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=ibm]}">
<![CDATA[
select * from html where url=@url and xpath='//option[@selected="selected"] | //input[@maxlength="2"] | //input[@maxlength="4"]'
]]>
</query>
<javascript execution-start-time="3" execution-stop-time="462" execution-time="459" instructions-used="46403" table-name="yahoo.finance.stocks"/>
<user-time>464</user-time>
<service-time>2251</service-time>
<build-version>0.2.2525</build-version>
</diagnostics>
<results>
<stock symbol="ibm">
<CompanyName/>
<start>1962-01-02</start>
<end>2014-06-03</end>
<Sector>Technology</Sector>
<Industry>Information Technology Services</Industry>
<FullTimeEmployees>431212</FullTimeEmployees>
</stock>
</results>
</query>
<!--  total: 464  -->
<!--  engine4.yql.bf1.yahoo.com  -->
```

Comment: It seems your entire code is `null`    :/

Comment: Sorry I thought I pasted it, long day :)

Comment: Please make sure to show small piece of XML related to your post. There are way too many ways to get XPath to return "no nodes found" - case sensitivity, namespaces, wrong node... At least link to documentation.

Comment: This question "lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem"?  There was enough there for me to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I have edited the question to provide a sample output of what yahoo would return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doc` is not null.  `node` is null, however, and this is because your XPath expression is wrong.

The name of the root element in the XML document you fetch is `query`, but your XPath expression `/results/stock/FullTimeEmployees` only matches if the root element has name `results`.  As there are no matching nodes, [`SelectSingleNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw(v=vs.110).aspx) returns null.

Try changing your XPath to either

```
/query/results/stock/FullTimeEmployees
```

or perhaps

```
//results/stock/FullTimeEmployees
```

(`//results` matches any element with name `results` at any depth in the document.)